# How to delete the Collections in firebase Cloud Firestore after n hours of its creation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a database that can store people's data and I want to refresh the data in the "TimeSlot" path for every 24 hours. I need to delete the complete database once n hours are completed and start collecting a new set of data from the next day.
The link to the image is given Below.

[This how my Database setup Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHdeX.png)

// this is how I am creating the TimeSlot dataBase

@IBAction func bookASlot(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    let date = Date()
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString = df.string(from: date)
    let userMail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!
    //search user table for entry that matches the current users email
    db.collection("Users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: userMail as Any )
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                //if we are here there can be only ONE user with this email adress, since we are logged in
                //so the array with our search results can contain only one entry
                let document = querySnapshot?.documents[0]
                let name = document?.documentID
                let id = document?.get("uniqueId")

                db.collection("TimeSlots")
                    .whereField("name", isEqualTo: name!)
                    .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                        if let error = err {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            //there can, if any, only be one prior booking
                            if (querySnapshot?.count == 0) {
                                //None found -> book slot
                                db.collection("TimeSlots").document(name!).setData([
                                    "name": name as Any,
                                    "time": dateString,
                                    "uniqueId": id!
                                ]) { err in
                                    if let err = err {
                                        print("Could not book because of: \(err)")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Slot booked!")
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                print("already booked")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

so once it is created then it should be stored for a certain number of hours and then the list should start a new after that period of time.

Sorry if I couldn't put my question Properly. Please and Thankyou

Comment: Please include database structures in the question. If that link breaks it will make the question useless to future readers.

Comment: *delete the complete database* Are you stating you want to delete everything within the TimeSlots collection every 24 hours? So something like a cron job will do that - see [Scheduled Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

Answer (score 1):

if you want delete all collenction path you need to do for loop all collection then call model and in the for loop you need to call again collection

```
       let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener { querysnapshott, err in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
            } else {
                if querysnapshott?.isEmpty != true && querysnapshott != nil {
                    self.collectionmoldel.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    
                    for document in querysnapshott!.documents {
                        let collection = collectionmodel(Name: document.get("name") as? String,
                                                  time: document.get("time") as? String,
                                                  documentID: document.documentID)
                        
                        
                        db.collection("Users").document(document.documentID).delete() { err in
                            if let err = err {
                                print(err.localizedDescription)
                            } else {
                                print("all path deleted")
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
                self.tableview.reloadData()
                
            }
            
        }
```